# ASP.NET MVC 4 Redirecting the Response in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

so basically I have a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and in it I override one method which looks something like this

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool shouldEnter = true;
    string redirUrl = "SomeController/SomeAction";
    // some checks here which change the value of shouldEnter;
    if (!shouldEnter)
    {
        filterContext.HttpCOntext.Response.Redirect(redirUrl);
    }
}
```

this is a very simple implementation of `ActionFilterAttribute`. Basically I check something and than decide to let the guy in or not. If I'm not letting him in than I should redirect him to some URL and I do that with the above implementation of `OnActionExecuting` method. but the thing is that before it goes to the someUrl the action he requested action gets executed first. Suppose I've request the page at `~/SomeController/YouShouldNotEnterHere` and this action has that attribute on it. the `OnActionExecuting` gets invoked and than I suppose that the corresponding action of `redirUrl` (which is mentioned in `OnActionExecuting` method ) will get invoked because I redirected the `Response` to it, but no, first the corresponding Action of /SomeController/YouShouldNotEnterHere gets invoked (but not drawn actually in browser, but the action still consumes time) and than the corresponding action of `redirUrl` gets invoked (and drawn in browser). Is this some kind of bug? or this is supposed to work this way ? anyway what can I do t

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC : Response.Redirect(url, TRUE) does not stop request processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187323/asp-net-mvc-response-redirecturl-true-does-not-stop-request-processing)

Comment: `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult { Url = redirUrl };`

Comment: @felickz that actually helped write an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing authorization, the proper attribute to use in this case is an `AuthorizeAttribute`

This will code will fix your existing attribute:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult { Url = redirUrl };
```

Comment: So you want to say that I cannot achieve what I want using ActionFilterAttribute ?

Comment: @Dima edited my post with way to redirect in your existing attribute

Comment: There is a specific reason why `AuthorizeAttribute` exists.  It runs before any `ActionFilterAttribute` which means there is the possibility of creating a security whole if you don't use it.

Comment: @erik is correct, you have no control over the order that similar attributes run... therefore if you truly do not want to do any other processing unless // some checks here which change the value of shouldEnter; .. then you want to use the AuthorizeAttribute. Although, the simple code fix above will prevent the controller/action from getting hit as you explain in your question .. As developers we should think about these things ;)