# Response.Redirect not working inside an custom ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, action-filter

My code is the following

```
public class SessionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (/*condition*/)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://www.someurl.com",true);

        }
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Now, the question is WHY does the action that is has [SessionCheck] applied to it STILL executes.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: should this be tagged ASP.NET MVC too?

Answer (score 9):

Don't use Response.Redirect, rather replace the Result on the context with a RedirectResult.   This will terminate processing in the filter chain and cause the redirect response to be sent immediately.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult( "http://www.someurl.com" );
```